# connect a php $post_data[ with html code

Tags: php, html, postdata

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$post_data['firstname'] = '';
$post_data['lastname'] = '';
$post_data['address'] = '';


foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value)
{
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://example.com/app.php');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo "Result: " . $result . "<br><br>";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . curl_error($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
```

How do I connect it to an HTML form so that someone can enter their details in an HTML page and its value will be redirected to this PHP code?

my HTML code is:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="my_php.php">
<input name="firstname" type="text" ID="firstname" value="first name">
<input name="lastname" type="text" ID="lastname" value="last name">
<input name="address" type="text" ID="address" value="address">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write something like this:
PAGE 1 - HTML - page1.html

```
<FORM ACTION='page2.php' METHOD='POST'>
<input name="firstname" type="text" ID="lastname" value="first name">
<input name="lastname" type="text" ID="lastname" value="last name">
<input name="address" type="text" ID="address" value="address">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

PAGE 2 - PHP - page2.php

```
<?PHP
echo $_POST['firstname'];
echo $_POST['lastname'];
echo $_POST['address'];
?>
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that you don't need in the first page, the following code: _ID="lastname" value="first name"_, and same for the others. Php Post works only with _name="firstname"_

Comment: when there is 
    "foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value)"
we can not use
    "$_POST['']"

and one field i have to use in that is
    "$post_data['ip_address'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];"

is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal. Example, if the input `name` is `Name`, then you would do:

```
<?php
echo 'Your name is ' . $_POST['Name'];
?>
```

Comment: actually i can't use $_POST instead of $POST_DATA

Comment: Well, `$_POST` is the method by which you get the actualy POST data... Why can't you use it?

Comment: if i use the $_POST instead if $POST_DATA then i'm getting following error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Answer (score 0):

my_php.PHP

```
$post_data = $_POST;
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, i have inserted this code in my php code and it is under review with my service provider and it will be cleared out within 2 days.
Hopefully it will work